# After Effects: controlling slider in ExtendScript

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I'm newbie in After Effects. I've learned how to control slider from expressions. Now I need to get value of slider in script (jsx/extendscript). How can I achieve that?

I've tried (in *.jsx): `var a = comp.layer("Slider 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider")[0];`

Result:

> After Effects error: Unable to call "setValue" because of parameter 1.
>   Value "NaN" of element 0 in the array is not a valid float.

It means that value of slider is not set yet?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is a example:

```
var slider = comp.layers.addNull();
slider.name = "Slider";
slider.effect.addProperty("ADBE Slider Control")("Slider");
slider.effect("Slider Control").property("Slider").setValue(100);

var a = slider.effect("Slider Control").property("Slider");
var titleTriangle = comp.layers.addShape();
titleTriangle.name = ("Title Triangle");
var titleTriangleGroup = titleTriangle.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Group");
var titleTriangleFill= titleTriangleGroup.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill");
titleTriangleFill.property("Color").setValue([0.68,0.29,0.29,1]);

// using 'a' here
titleTriangle.property("Position").setValue([a,188]);
```

Comment: Please paste all code here. It is difficult to understand, where can be problem, when you are seeing only part of code.

Comment: @Shultc, thank you for response. I have added an example.

Comment: Sounds like you need to know about Redefinery's **RD_Gimme_Props** script. It's a script that allows you to find the correct path for any composition element: http://bit.ly/1XTIzh0 There's a whole bunch of tools there for extendscript developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out - **.value** after slider.effect("Slider Control").property("Slider") and it works.

```
var a = slider.effect("Slider Control").property("Slider").value
```